# Intel Xeon E7-4807 vs Intel Xeon X5690

Tags: performance, hardware, central-processing-unit, xeon

We replaced our main line of business server with a new one.  The old server had dual Xeon X5690s in it (2 generation old chip), the new server has quad Xeon E7-4807s.  We expect processor performance to at least stay the same.

Our main java app showed a 50% performance hit and on running a sysbench against the two machines, the old processors were 50% faster.

Is this a particularly bad chip ?  Is there something we are missing performance wise ?

(Os on both is Centos 5.10 x86_64 and memory is 128GB)

Comment: Is your app able to take advantage of multiple cores?

Comment: Older chip. Take a look at the [E5-4607 v2](http://ark.intel.com/products/75794/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-4607-v2-15M-Cache-2_60-GHz) for an example of something similar but recent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Kinda...**

This is a good lesson in resource-planning and making hardware decisions across CPU lines and generations. I've had the unique experience of needing high-end CPUs for applications in a few different industries, but also the luxury of being able to test and benchmark before major architecture changes.

As a result of this, my rule is to examine the product lines and move to processors that have comparable positions in the portfolio when you make hardware changes.

What's better? A 2010 Mercedes S-Class or a 2014 Mercedes C-Class? *It depends...*

- The Intel [Westmere x5690](http://ark.intel.com/products/52576/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5690-12M-Cache-3_46-GHz-6_40-GTs-Intel-QPI) was a 3.47GHz hex-core processor. It was Intel's top-end mainstream server CPU during its product lifetime.
- The Intel [Westmere-EX E7-4807](http://ark.intel.com/products/53569/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E7-4807-18M-Cache-1_86-GHz-4_80-GTs-Intel-QPI) was a 1.86GHz hex-core processor meant for quad-socket boards. This CPU was at the *bottom* of the product line. It was released in the same quarter as the x5690.

[**Intel Comparison Chart**](http://ark.intel.com/compare/53569,52576) - Comparing the x5690 and E7-4807

**So what's wrong?**

Your "new" server is also running an older architecture. Remember, the bigger server platforms (quad-socket, etc.) don't rev as often as the smaller systems. You have a CPU that's running around half the clock speed of the previous CPU, but of the same generation, thus the performance drop. The E7-4807 is also missing [Turbo Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost).

I'd be interested to know what prompted the upgrade. You likely *had* the raw CPU performance you needed. Was it memory or another factor? What was the bottleneck?

A better move if you simply needed additional cores would have been a newer dual-socket system, but with top-line Intel E5-2643v2 (3.5GHz) or E5-2697v2 (2.9GHz) CPUs.

Comment: This sounds more like a _downgrade_ than an upgrade.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Yes, a big downgrade. That's why I'm curious how this server was chosen.

Comment: Was trying to optimize database performance, moved to 2u Quad processor mostly to get space in the chassis for a better disk subsystem - decent RAID controller running SSDs so I could put the database and logs on different disks.  
This did work - db performance is greater than 2x improved, but had the unintended consequence for tanking main app performance.  Turns out the CPU was far more important performance wise than the db...

Comment: @David well, it's possible to acquire a 2U 2-socket server with the disk expansion you need. Good luck in your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Your "new" server is also using 2 generation old processors.  They are a newer, lower power iteration of that generation.

Unless you're intimately familiar with processor architecture, it's a good idea to **stay within the same family and TDP** when you're upgrading.  Intel's nomenclature isn't always as straight forward as it could be, but the current replacement for the X5600 series is the [E5-2600V2 series](http://ark.intel.com/products/series/75291/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2600-v2-Product-Family).

Here's a [comparison of the processors](http://ark.intel.com/compare/52576,53569,75268) in your old server, your new server, and the current replacement for your old server.